# React Rails component: manually triggering a re-render

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

In Rails, I've got a set of Bootstrap tabs on a page with a React component on each one, ie:

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane">
  ...
  <%= react_component('PeopleWidget', person_id: @person.id) %>  
  ...
</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane">
  ...
  <%= react_component('ContentWidget', content_id: @content.id) %>
  ...
</div>
```

The components:

- Do not talk with each other
- Update a RESTful backend

Now:

- `PeopleWidget` can update a person's permissions in the backend
- This should change `ContentWidget` to read-only behavior

My tactical solution is:

- On Bootstrap event when `tab-2` is shown, I would like to manually trigger `ContentWidget` render.
- This will initiate loading updated details from backend
- `ContentWidget` will have proper updated behavior

This feels like a workaround but I have a timeline :)

**I can't figure out how to manually trigger the `ContentWidget` to re-render. Is this possible?**

Comment: if the state of the component changes, it will rerender. LIke a call to `setState` for example. Or new property values being provided. I wouldn't expect however a render to trigger data to be loaded. You shouldn't rely on `render` for a trigger. It might be called too often (or not enough).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could employ a tactic from Flux: you could set up an event listener in your component, and when the event happens, re-render using `forceUpdate`.

In Flux, components listen to stores. In your case, you could listen to the [events triggered by Bootstrap tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events).

For example, to handle the event when the tab is shown:

```
var ContentWidget = React.createClass({
    _handleTabShow: function() {
      this.forceUpdate()
      // any other reload/re-render code here, too
    },

    componentWillMount: function() { 
      // start listening for show event:
      $('#tab-2').on('shown.bs.tab', this._handleTabShow)
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
      // clean up the handler when the component is removed:
      $('#tab-2').off('shown.bs.tab', this._handleTabShow)     
    }

    // The rest of your component code 
    // goes here....
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Obvious now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forceUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate) to make the component re-render

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a brief code example in the context of my code? I've seen ``forceUpdate`` in the docs but don't know how to use it in my existing code.